# getting a UnicodeEncodeError when trying to write a JSON file

Tags: python, python-unicode

Given input file with content:

```
{ "symbol": "°C" }
```

And this code:

```
import sys
import json

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as ifile, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as ofile:
    json.dump(json.load(ifile), ofile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get an error:

```
$ python2.7 play.py input.json output.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play.py", line 5, in <module>
    json.dump(json.load(ifile), ofile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But Python 3 works fine:

```
$ python3.3 play.py input.json output.json
$ cat output.json 
{
    "symbol": "°C"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError when writing to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939692/unicodeencodeerror-when-writing-to-a-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module to deal with it by declaring the encoding of the file:

```
import sys
import json
import codecs

with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', 'utf-8') as ifile, codecs.open(sys.argv[2], 'w', 'utf-8') as ofile:
    json.dump(json.load(ifile), ofile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```