# Error writing a file with file.write in Python. UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, decode, encode, fwrite

I have never dealt with encoding and decoding strings, so I am quite the newbie on this front.  I am receiving a UnicodeEncodeError when I try to write the contents I read from another file to a temporary file using file.write in Python. I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 41333: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is what I am doing in my code.  I am reading an XML file and getting the text from the "mydata" tag.  I then iterate through mydata to look for CDATA

```
    parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
    root = etree.parse(myfile.xml, parser)
    data = root.findall('./mydata')
    # iterate through list to find text (lua code) contained in elements containing CDATA
    for item in myData:
        myCode = item.text

    # Write myCode to a temporary file.
    tempDirectory = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix="", prefix="TEST_THIS_")
    file = open(tempDirectory + os.path.sep + "myCode.lua", "w")

    file.write(myCode + "\n")
    file.close()
```

It fails with the UnicodeEncodeError when I hit the following line:

```
file.write(myCode + "\n")
```

How should I properly encode and decode this?

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError when writing to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939692/unicodeencodeerror-when-writing-to-a-file)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python2.7's `open` function does not transparently handle unicode characters like python3 does.  There is [extensive documentation on this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), but if you want to write unicode strings directly without decoding them, you can try this

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8')
>>> f.write(u'\u201c')
```

For comparison, this is how the error happen

```
>>> f = open(filename, 'w')
>>> f.write(u'\u201c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```