# why i get the "'NoneType' object has no attribute" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I had made a script for scraping some data from a web site but it only runs for a few few pages and after that it will stop with this message "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'".Another error which appear sometimes is this:

```
File "scrappy3.py", line 31, in <module>
f.writerow(doc_details)
File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015f' in 
position 251: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can You please give me an advice how to resolve those errors.This is my script:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()
page = 1
f = csv.writer(open("./doctors.csv", "w", newline=''))
while page <= 5153:
    url = "http://www.sfatulmedicului.ro/medici/n_s0_c0_h_s0_e0_h0_pagina" + str(page)
    data = requests.get(url)
    print ('scraping page ' + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html.parser")
    for liste in soup.find_all('li',{'class':'clearfix'}):
        doc_details = []
        url_doc = liste.find('a').get('href')
        for a in liste.find_all('a'):
            if a.has_attr('name'):
                doc_details.append(a['name'])   
        data2 = requests.get(url_doc)       
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data2.text,"html.parser")
        a_tel = soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'}).a              
        tel_tag=a_tel['onclick']
        tel = tel_tag[tel_tag.find("$(this).html("):tel_tag.find(");")].lstrip("$(this).html(") 
        doc_details.append(tel)         
    f.writerow(doc_details)

    page += 1
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Which line are you getting this? Maybe you can post the whole error message with the stack trace.

Comment: `soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'})` does not find anything, returns `None`, so the `.a` fails.

Comment: @deceze what is curious is that the program stops at a random page and i had checked on that page if that div is there and it is.So I guess i need to implement a function that retries to get that url and parse it again until it finds the div.Can you help me with my second error too?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is here

```
   a_tel = soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'}).a
```

`soup.find` is obviously not finding the `div` with the sought class. The return value is `None` and this by definition has no attributes.

You should check and decide if to `continue` with further queries in the loop or bail out. For example:

```
   div_contact = soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'})
   if div_contact is None:
       continue

   a_tel = div_contact.a
```

You could also try with an `try .. except` block to cover more cases (like the `div` actually not having what you expect)

```
   div_contact = soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'})
   try:
       a_tel = div_contact.a
   except AttributeError:
       continue
```

which is in theory more Pythonic. Your choice in any case.

Continuous and continued error checking is part of a program.

Comment: what is curious is that the program stops at a random page and i had checked on that page if that div is there and it is.So I guess i need to implement a function that retries to get that url and parse it again until it finds the div.Can you help me with my second error too?

Comment: You will probably run into the same error. Even if it visually seems to you to be the *same* div with the same class ... it's obviously not and that means you will have to account for extra cases.

Comment: With regards to encoding ... you have to decide what to do with the error, but you can have a look at this other answer for `write` which covers Unicode encoding when using `write`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392377/error-writing-a-file-with-file-write-in-python-unicodeencodeerror

Comment: Regarding to encoding i had solved it by adding to the csv.writer encoding='utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

```
resp_find = soup.find('div',{'class':'contact_doc add_comment'})
if resp_find is not None:
    a_tel = resp_find.a
```

You can query if the response of soup.find() is a NoneType object, if not you can apply the .a

Or you ensure that the soup.find() method never give back a NoneType object, so you have to investigate why this method give a NoneType object

Comment: what is curious is that the program stops at a random page and i had checked on that page if that div is there and it is.So I guess i need to implement a function that retries to get that url and parse it again until it finds the div.Can you help me with my second error too?